# Bit increase when averaging?

Tags: computer-science, binary, average

I have a given number $N$ of binary numbers, that are stored using a given number $B$ of bits. $B$ is the same for all the numbers.

For example, thease values where $N = 4, B = 4$.

```
0000 (zero)
0001 (one)
1111 (fifteen)
1001 (nine)
```

Q: I take the average, how many bits $R$ do I need to store the result with an ordinary binary number?

---

My workings before the answer:

The average of the above example, adding extra bits to the result:

```
0000 (zero)
0001 (one)
1111 (fifteen)
1001 (nine)
```

=

```
0110.01 (6.25)
```

One might assume that combining all four, 4 bit numbers requires 16 bits, $R = N * B$, however many of thease values will represent impossible results. For example when $N = B = 4$, $R$ cannot equal $0000.000000000001$.

So I know that in just the case where $N = B = 4$, that $5 < R < 16$.

Comment: The question is a little vague. What would you do with the numbers $00, 00, 01$? Store an infinite string of bits?

Comment: If you have $N=3$ and $B=1$, and the numbers $0$, $0$, and $1$, what is their average denoted in binary?  Taking this into account, do you wish to invoke any special restrictions on the possible values of $N$?  E.g. $N$ must be a power of two...

Comment: @copper.hat and JMoravitz. Assume we are not using $N$ values where this is a problem, such as $N = 3$. If you want to include cases such as $N = 3$, then include enough bits to differentiate it from other possible values.

Comment: @JMoravitz If you have an answer for specifically where N is a power of two, I'd consider this a good enough answer to mark as correct, and it covers what I need the answer for.

Comment: If N is a power of two, think about what happens in the averaging process (think of averaging as first adding them all up and then dividing by N).  As N is a power of two, this has the effect of shifting the decimal place.  Couple this with the fact that the average cannot exceed the maximum value and reach a conclusion

Comment: @JMoravitz TY :) Where $N$ is a power of 2, $R = B + log2(N)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p\neq 2$ is a prime factor of $N$ and choose $N$ numbers such that their sum is ${N \over p}$, then the result is ${ 1\over p}$ 
which has a non terminating binary expansion. Hence the only non problematic $N$ are those that are powers of $2$.

So, suppose $N = 2^n$ for some $n$ (hence dividing by $N$ corresponds to
a right shift of $\log_2 N$ bits). Since the sum of the numbers must lie
between $0$ and $2^n (2^{B+1}-1)\le 2^{n+B+1} -1$, we see that at most
$n+B$ bits are required, and by considering $2^n-1 $ copies of the number
$2^B$ and one number of $2^B+1$, we see that the sum is $1+2^{n+B}$, hence
at least $n+B$ bits are required,
hence we see that $B+\log_2 N$ bits are required.

Answer (score 0):

$N ∈ ℕ, B ∈ ℕ$

---

Where $N$ is a power of two, $N = 2^{∈ℕ}$, then $R = B + log2(N)$.

In some cases, this way will require an infinite number of bits, then $R = ∞$, or at times more practically $R = B + log2(N) + ∈\{0, 1\}$.

---

256 bytes are able to be included in an average before the result requires 2 bytes to store.